# F# HTTP Post, Reading statuscode response

Tags: http, post, f#

Im using Fsharp.DATA to send a HTTP POST Request and read the response statuscode. In this instance I'm expecting a 302(Re-direct) on success and 200 (OK) on failure. I can see on fiddler I'm getting a 302 which in turn is re-directing and thus generating a 'GET' request. In my code I want to read the statuscode '302' to signify to me that it has worked. My codes response however is giving me the statuscode of the followed up 'GET' request (200) and not from my initial post request (302). At least... I assume that is why its reading out a 200 instead of 302 despite my initial POST request having a 302 statuscode (shown in fiddler)

[image: The first POST I send returns a 302 which generates the second 200]

```
let postTEST cap:string =
if Http.Request("https://foo.com/m=account-creation/create_account",
     body = FormValues [
    "foo", "foo";
    "foo", "foo";
    "email1", email;
    "onlyOneEmail", "1";
    "password1", foo;
    "onlyOnePassword", "1";
    "foo", "foo";
    "foo", "12";
    "month", "10";
    "year", "foo";
    "foo", cap;
    "foo", "foo";]).StatusCode = 320 then "worked"
    else "Not worked"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable following redirects by customizing the HTTP request:

```
Http.Request(
    "https://example.url",
    body = FormValues [],
    customizeHttpRequest = fun r -> r.AllowAutoRedirect <- false; r)
```

For more information see [the FSharp.Data section "Customizing the HTTP request"](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html) and [the HttpWebRequest docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect).